# value of fit_generator parameters

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, cnn

I am doing simple CNN based binary image classification on classifying types of waste as organic and recyclable using image augmentation. How ever I have a doubt.

[image: First part of the code]

[image: Second part of the code]

[image: Results]

In the third figure i have set the steps_per_epoch = 22564/32= 705 where 32 is batch size and validation_steps as 2513/32 = 79 as per documentation does that mean out of 22564 training and 2513 validation samples 705 and 79 are trained and validated ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Can you please paste and properly format your code?

Comment: I am sorry i dont know how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is the steps per epoch. One step is taking 32 images(batch size) So, 709*32 images used in that epoch and validated with 79*32 images.